# Merge in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is my query, I want to merge data from the source into the destination (I'm a beginner in SQL Server

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(NoContratAdhesion char(8) );
DECLARE @rqt as nvarchar (800000)

SET = 'SELECT * 
       FROM infocentre.[dbo].[TCtrCollRG] as RG
       INNER JOIN SSIS_Temp.dbo.TLID_ADH_RG1_HUM AS RG1 ON RG.NoContratAdhesion = RG1.NoContratAdhesion'

USING (SELECT * FROM SSIS_Temp.dbo.Tmp_CollRG_sans_cle_HUM 
       WHERE Flag_doublons <> '1') AS SOURCE
ON (TARGET.Nocontratadhesion = SOURCE.NoContratAdhesion
AND TARGET.NoAvenant = SOURCE.NoAvenant  
AND TARGET.CodeRG=SOURCE.CodeRG)  

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET  
    THEN 
        INSERT ([NoContratAdhesion], [NoAvenant], [NoAdherent],
                [CodeProduitCible], [CodeRG], [Optionnel], [Retenu],
                [Retarde], [DateDebutValiditeRG], [DateFinValiditeRG],
                [DateMajRG], [DateInsertPl], [DateMajPl], Date_CHARG_SIAD, FLAG_DELTA)
        VALUES (SOURCE.[NoContratAdhesion], SOURCE.[NoAvenant], NULL, 
                SOURCE.[CodeProduitCible], SOURCE.[CodeRG], SOURCE.[Optionnel], SOURCE.[Retenu],
                SOURCE.[Retarde], SOURCE.[DateDebutValiditeRG], SOURCE.[DateFinValiditeRG],
                SOURCE.[DateMajRG], SOURCE.[DateInsertPl], SOURCE.[DateMajPl], GETDATE(), 'I')

WHEN MATCHED

     THEN UPDATE SET

 TARGET.[NoContratAdhesion]=SOURCE.[NoContratAdhesion]

      ,TARGET.[NoAvenant]=SOURCE.[NoAvenant]

      ,TARGET.[NoAdherent]=NULL

      ,TARGET.[CodeProduitCible]=SOURCE.[CodeProduitCible]

      ,TARGET.[CodeRG]=SOURCE.[CodeRG]

      ,TARGET.[Optionnel]=SOURCE.[Optionnel]

      ,TARGET.[Retenu]=SOURCE.[Retenu]

      ,TARGET.[Retarde]=SOURCE.[Retarde]

      ,TARGET.[DateDebutValiditeRG]=SOURCE.[DateDebutValiditeRG]

      ,TARGET.[DateFinValiditeRG]=SOURCE.[DateFinValiditeRG]

      ,TARGET.[DateMajRG]=SOURCE.[DateMajRG]

      ,TARGET.[DateInsertPl]=SOURCE.[DateInsertPl]

      ,TARGET.[DateMajPl]=SOURCE.[DateMajPl]

         , TARGET.Date_CHARG_SIAD =getdate()

         ,TARGET.FLAG_DELTA='M'

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE

    THEN DELETE 

OUTPUT Source.NoContratAdhesion

     INTO @T;             
DELETE infocentre.[dbo].[TCtrCollRG]

WHERE NoContratAdhesion     in (SELECT NoContratAdhesion

                     FROM @T);
                                  select count(*) from infocentre.[dbo].[TCtrCollRG]
```

I want to delete data if there are not in destination or update if exists, i tried this query but have errors.

Can you help me please?

Comment: There's no `MERGE` and the first `set` doesn't set anything. Post something that actually compiles. Don't try to write one huge query and try to make it compile *after* the fact

Comment: I would suggest you to read first the article about MERGE- you don't even have MERGE keyword in your query. And dynamic SQL is not for L"i'ma begginer in SQL Server"

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. A _minimal_ and _complete_ example helps us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nvarchar` does not permit a length of 800000.  Your `set` command does not describe what variable is being set.  You have no `merge` clause to indicate what your target table is.

At minimum, you need to change this:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(NoContratAdhesion char(8) );
DECLARE @rqt as nvarchar (800000)
set= 'SELECT * from infocentre.[dbo].[TCtrCollRG] as RG
 INNER JOIN SSIS_Temp.dbo.TLID_ADH_RG1_HUM AS RG1 on RG.NoContratAdhesion=RG1.NoContratAdhesion'

USING (SELECT *  from  SSIS_Temp.dbo.Tmp_CollRG_sans_cle_HUM where Flag_doublons <> '1')   AS SOURCE
ON   (TARGET.Nocontratadhesion = SOURCE.NoContratAdhesion

and TARGET.NoAvenant = SOURCE.NoAvenant  and TARGET.CodeRG=SOURCE.CodeRG)
```

into this:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (NoContratAdhesion char(8));
DECLARE @rqt nvarchar(4000);
set @rqt = '
    SELECT * from infocentre.[dbo].[TCtrCollRG] as RG
    INNER JOIN SSIS_Temp.dbo.TLID_ADH_RG1_HUM AS RG1 on RG.NoContratAdhesion=RG1.NoContratAdhesion
';

merge   @T target
USING   (SELECT * from  SSIS_Temp.dbo.Tmp_CollRG_sans_cle_HUM where Flag_doublons <> '1')   AS SOURCE
ON      TARGET.Nocontratadhesion = SOURCE.NoContratAdhesion
and     TARGET.NoAvenant = SOURCE.NoAvenant  and TARGET.CodeRG=SOURCE.CodeRG
```

After a cursory scan, I don't believe I see a major issue with the rest of your logic.

This is assuming you're in fact trying to merge from the real table into `@T` and not the other way around.  Otherwise switch the `merge` and the `using` statements.